# Long to wide table

Tags: r

I have neuropsychological testing scores in the long format for a *n* number of subjects. I need to convert it to wide but also reducing dimensionality by summarizing scores by the testing type. I want z-scores for the test group.

Let's get into the MWE.

```
id <- c("ana","ana", "brad","ana","brad", "matt", "matt")
assessment <- c("memory", "memory", "attention",  "verbal",  "attention", "memory", "attention")
value <- c(0.000,1.000,0.895,0.000,15.000, 3, 5)

mydata<-data.frame(id, assessment, value)
```

mydata looks like:

```
> mydata
    id assessment  value
1  ana     memory  0.000
2  ana     memory  1.000
3 brad  attention  0.895
4  ana     verbal  0.000
5 brad  attention 15.000
6 matt     memory  3.000
7 matt  attention  5.000
```

- How to convert from long to wide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need a sequence variable by group

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(i1=row_number()) %>% 
   spread(assessment, value)
```

---

Or using `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(mydata), id+rowid(id) ~assessment, value.var = "value")
```